# How to solve TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[uint8]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which I want to plot using stacked chart for all columns

```
    date              company1           company2           company3
0   2015-09-30  0.1729652326951854  5.10825384154414    5.28662587089132
1   2015-12-31  0.33177760613144625 5.341402694012068   7.757158664745589
2   2016-03-31  0.45978954321258786 0.601947573082123   14.280848001613228
3   2016-06-30  0.08512062667254938 0.26628902842588686 9.342680735839917
4   2016-09-30  0.07052086314882283 10.032170981625246  8.964205526466738
5   2016-12-31  0.06143896111634454 10.06041088786925   8.3778390910586
6   2017-03-31  0.03742645731812014 7.156923204928792   6.793302965780993
7   2017-06-30  0.1032395546373315  5.438273795868809   4.857798532828831
```

I did the following

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6), dpi= 80)
ax = exchanges_disagg_data.plot.area(legend=None, figsize=(9,6), alpha=0.9)
```

and i get the following error message.

```
TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[uint8]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

Then i tried

```
df.date= df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and i get the plot but instead of date time x ticks, i just get index numbers...

This is very frustrating, would anyone know how to solve this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Graphs can be drawn using only the graphing function of pandas. The graph is created after indexing a date column. `df.set_index(df['date'], drop=True, inplace=True);df.plot.area(legend=None, figsize=(9, 6), alpha=0.9)` I just encountered a puzzling error, so I'm not sure if I can reproduce it in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `np.nan` is float type and `pd.NaT` is of datetime null type. Problem with your code is that null values have been filled with np.nan

I got the same error while doing the following thing....

```
df['date'] = np.where((df['date2'].notnull()) & (df['date3'].notnull()),df['date2']-df['date3'],np.nan)
```

problem here is date difference of date2 and date3 is of datetime type but the type of "np.nan" is float/int. For saving it to df['date'], datatype should be same. In datetime type the null date is "pd.NaT". So when I replace the above code with below. It worked for me. You can try the same..

```
df['date'] = np.where((df['date2'].notnull()) & (df['date3'].notnull()),df['date2']-df['date3'],pd.NaT)
```

So you can replace the nulls present in your data with `pd.NaT` instead of `np.nan`

you can use below thing as well...

```
df['date'].replace(np.NaN, pd.NaT)
```

or

```
df['date'].fillna(pd.NaT)
```

Hope it is helpful for you :)